# How to debug IOS app with accessory attached

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing an app that I need to see the xcode console output i.e. the following

```
2019-12-27 13:14:37.188270-1000 HelloDroneIOS13[2076:1783918] [arsdkengine] Create ArsdkEngine
2019-12-27 13:14:37.189316-1000 HelloDroneIOS13[2076:1783918] [gsdk.core] Loading engine ArsdkEngine
2019-12-27 13:14:37.189450-1000 HelloDroneIOS13[2076:1783918] [gsdk.core] Starting engines
2019-12-27 13:14:37.206437-1000 HelloDroneIOS13[2076:1783918] [gsdk.core.utility.internet] Started listening for Internet connectivity changes.
```

I have an accessory I need to attach so I can't have it connected to my laptop when running and it is crashing so I need to figure out the reason.  I tried connecting it to my laptop after it crashed then from xcode Window->Devices and Simulators -> Open Console.  See image:

[image]
  This seems to only show the latest console outputs.  Where can I access the saved outputs when it crashed? instead of the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an accessory I need to attach so I can't have it connected to my laptop when running

Yes you can. Configure your device for wireless connection to Xcode. Now you can attach the accessory device and receive Console output at the same time. That is exactly why wireless Xcode debugging was invented.

(Check "Connect via network", visible in your screen shot.)